# Is Collection a subtype of Object in Java?

Tags: java

Is `Collection<?>` a subtype of `Object` in Java? This might be a stupid question, but isn't `Object` the root of every class?

Comment: Object is the root of every class, except interfaces (like Collection), Object class itself and the primitive classes.

Comment: @Peter: The primitive types are not technically classes. ;)

Comment: @cdhowie Neither are interfaces. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `Collection<?>` is a reference type and therefore a subtype of `java.lang.Object`.

This is easy to check:

```
import java.util.Collection;

class Assign {
    public Object check(Collection<?> things) {
        return things;
    }
}
```

Just as well, because it allows us to have collections of collections, for instance.

[JLS 4.10.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10) sayeth:

> Given a type declaration for
>   C, the direct supertypes of
>   the parameterized type (§4.5)
>   C are all of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - The type Object, if C is an
>     interface type with no direct
>     superinterfaces.

Comment: It is not a subtype of `Object`, but it is convertible to `Object`.

Comment: @cdhowie JLS definition of Widening Reference Conversions: "A widening reference conversion exists from any type S to any type T, provided S is a subtype (§4.10) of T." http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190646

Answer (score 14):

No.  `Collection` is an interface, and interfaces cannot inherit from classes -- therefore they cannot inherit from `Object`.  (It does not make sense for an interface, which has no implementation, to inherit from a class, which can have an implementation.)

However, any class that implements `Collection` will obviously have to inherit from `Object`.  So you can treat objects implementing `Collection` as though they do inherit from `Object`, because ultimately they will have to.

It's a semantic difference, but an important distinction in OO theory.

**UPDATE:** For those challenging this answer with the Java spec, I refer you to this code sample, which indicates that either the spec is not implemented correctly, or is just plain wrong.

### TestInterface.java

```
public interface TestInterface {
    public void foo();
}
```

### Test.java

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class ti = TestInterface.class;

        Class sti = ti.getSuperclass();
        System.out.println("superclass is null: " + (sti == null));

        for (Method m : ti.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(m.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

On my system (`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)` according to `java -showversion`) the output of the compiled program is:

```
superclass is null: true
foo
```

So I'm sorry, but no, interfaces do not technically inherit from anything (except possibly other interfaces) and they do not inherit the methods of `Object`.

Comment: @Random: yes but of why oh why don't you also upvote the question? It's only the question that makes this answer worthy. SO makes me wants to p*ke when I see nonsense like this: a good question that gets only one vote and 9 upvotes for the answer.  I like the answer, but -1 sorry: it's not normal.  and +1 to the question.

Comment: Ah, nothing like being penalized for a good answer because of someone's grudge. \o/

Comment: @cdhowie It's wrong. `Collection<?>` is a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: It's not. I am putting together a code sample that demonstrates this.

Comment: @cdhowie: Sorry, but you're just plain wrong. An interface _is_ a subtype of `Object`. The fact that you can override methods declared by `Object` (such as `equals` and `hashCode`) on an interface (complete with `@Override` annotation) should be an indication to you here.

Comment: @cdhowie: Also take a look at Tom's updated answer... as he says, section 4.10.2 of the JLS states _specifically_ that any interface type is a subtype of `Object`. That is the correct answer, period. The fact that this got so many upvotes is embarassing.

Comment: @ColinD: The implementation doesn't follow the spec. See my updated answer.

Comment: @cdhowie: What the reflection API does here is meaningless in the context of this question. The question asks if the interface type `Collection` is a subtype of `Object`, and the only answer to that is _yes_.

Comment: @Webinator: I am terribly sorry that we do not have the same way to judge the upvoting system. At the end it's an opinion system, and your arguments are rather weak in the position that for a terrible question it can exists an incredibly well placed answer. Do you really think that asking if Collection extends Object (with out more data) is a worth-upvoting question? Yes? well go and upvote it. Trolling about it doesn't seem the best way to archive anything.

Comment: The implementation of `Class.getSuperclass` appears to follow its API docs. Like the method name, the API docs do not mention subtype or supertype.

Comment: @ColinD: Do not confuse inheritance with convertibility.

Comment: @cdhowie: You're the one who's confusing things here, sorry. An interface type _does_ inherit from `Object`. Several facts have been presented to you that make this clear, including: the JLS, the fact that a `Collection<Collection<?>>` is valid (when the collection's type parameter must be a subclass of `Object`), and the fact that `@Override` is legal on `Object` methods in interfaces, but you choose to ignore them.

Comment: Also note that the JLS defines inheritance to include inheritance of members from interfaces.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin, @ColinD I agree with you that the documentation says that you are right. And that I didn't even suspect it would be like that I belived that interfaces did not extend from Object, but I have one question, How is that cdhowie code gets a null in its getSuperclass() method? That doesn't defy the very idea behind the documentation? It seems that you can override Object methods even if it seems that de code says it is not a superclass. Could it be "yes and no" a really truthful answer? Thank you :)

Comment: @Random: No, it's simply that the `getSuperclass()` method does not define the subtype/supertype relationship. As Tom mentions, the method is not `getSupertype()` and doesn't mention "supertype" anywhere. The method also states "If this `Class` represents either the `Object` class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned." That is simply the contract of that particular API method, and doesn't say anything about the Java language's definition of what is a subtype of what. In Java, an interface type is a subtype of `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Any interface type is a subtype of `Object`.

I think a lot of the confusion here (by which I mean cdhowie's incorrect answer and the large number of upvotes it has received) centers around an incorrect understanding of the term "subtype". "Subtype" is a *compile-time* concept defined by the Java Language Specification that indicates a relationship between two types. While the subtype relationship is used various places in the JLS, a type `S` being a *subtype* of a type `T` effectively means that *an instance of S is always also an instance of T*. Given that, for a reference of type `S` to be assigned to a reference of type `T` without casting and without producing a compiler error, `S` *must be* a subtype of `T`!

Thus, the fact that the following code is legal is actually *proof* that the interface type `Collection` is considered a subtype of the type `Object` by the Java langauge, just as the JLS specifies.

```
Collection<?> collection = ...
Object obj = collection;
```

cdhowie's "proof" that his answer is correct does not actually prove anything other than that the methods `Class.getSuperclass()` and `Class.getMethods()` obey the contracts they specify in their documentation... this has nothing to do with Java's concept of a "type".

`Class.getSuperclass()`:

> If this `Class` represents either the `Object` class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned.

`Class.getMethods()`:

> This method returns an array of length 0 if this Class object represents a class or interface that has no public member methods, or if this Class object represents a primitive type or void.

Comment: Well said, especially the contract of "getSuperClass"