# Why is the difference in declaration of generic Lists?

Tags: java, generics, collections, jvm, compiler-errors

I want to decare two Lists:
First is a list of Integers. I decare it as:

```
  List<Integer> ints= Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
```

It works fine.

Second is a list of Objects. I declare it as:

```
  List<Object> objs= Arrays.asList(1,2.13,"three");
```

But it gives a error in eclipse as soon as I write it. The error is:

```
  Multiple markers at this line
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable> to 
 List<Object>
- Type safety: A generic array of Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable is created for
       a varargs parameter
```

Instead if I write

```
  List<Object> objs = Arrays.<Object>asList(1,2.13,"three");
```

It works fine.

I am not able figure out the reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9838799/1122645).

**15.12.2.7 Inferring Type Arguments Based on Actual Arguments**

> A supertype constraint T :> X implies that the solution is one of
>   supertypes of X. Given several such constraints on T, we can intersect
>   the sets of supertypes implied by each of the constraints, since the
>   type parameter must be a member of all of them. We can then choose the
>   most specific type that is in the intersection

The most restrictive type intersection between `String`,`Double` and `Integer` is both the interfaces `Comparable` and `Serializable`. So when you write

```
Arrays.asList(1,2.13,"three");
```

It infers `T` to be `implements Comparable<?>, Serializable`.Then it is as if you are doing

```
List<Object> objs = new List<T extends Comparable<?>, Serializable>
```

Obviously, this is not allowed.
On the other hand, when you specify `Object` explicitly using

```
Arrays.<Object>asList(1,2.13,"three");
```

no inference is made

Comment: Got it. Thanks for extremely good explanation. This will be a golden rule to apply in case of such confusions.

Answer (score 2):

Use this works perfect

```
List<? extends Object> objs = Arrays.asList(10,20.32,"test");

System.out.println(objs);
```

**Output:** [10, 20.32, test]

Comment: That's fine, but note that as far as the compiler is concerned, `List<Object>` is *not* the same as `List<? extends Object>`, and the OP may need a `List<Object>`

Comment: -1 As the OP stated, `Arrays.<Object>asList(1,2.13,"three")` works fine. The question was why the compiler fails to infer `Object`, not how to hack a solution.