# what does this mean? Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable> to List<Object>"

Tags: java, serialization

When I delete `Object>` in the `Array.Object`>`asList(1, 2.89, "three")`.

```
  List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(1, 2.89, "three");
```

It reminds me

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from List object&Comparable&Serializable> to List Object>

```
public class WildcardCopyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> str1 = Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz");
        List<String> str2 = Arrays.asList("11");
        LowerAndUpperBound.copy(str1, str2);

        System.out.println(str1);

        List<Object> objs = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, 2.89, "three");
        List<Integer>  ints = Arrays.asList(100);
        LowerAndUpperBound.copy(objs, ints);

        System.out.println(objs);

        List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(new Item("Java"), new Item("JSPS"));

        List<Book2> books = Arrays.asList(new Book2("J2EE", 100.89));
        LowerAndUpperBound.copy(items, books);

        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

My copy method:

```
  public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
      for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
          dest.set(i, src.get(i));
      }
```

Comment: Works fine for me without `<Object>`.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942467/why-is-the-difference-in-declaration-of-generic-lists